# PHPData from an array to variable

Tags: php

I've getting data from a MySQL database (gpio temperature sensor) and storing 1 row into a variable to use with pCharts. This is in php

If i create the variable manually this work

```
$sensor1c = "24.5,24.5,24.5,24.5,24.5,24.5,24.5,24.5,24.5,24.5,24.5,24.5,";
```

However if i get the data from the DB and then add it to a variable via a while loop it doesn't work.

```
$order = "SELECT sensor2c FROM (SELECT * FROM temperature ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12) sub ORDER BY id ASC;";
 $result = mysql_query($order); 

 while($data = mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {  
 $sensor1c .= $data[0];
 $sensor1c .= ",";
 }
```

Does anyone know why the two are different?
Also tried with no luck

```
$sensor1c = (string)$sensor1c;
```

Comment: Does the query have any results?

Comment: You could try with the `CONCAT_WS` function of MySql to get the result you want without looping.

Comment: The first thing you should do is add `mysql_query($order) or die(mysql_error());` to ensure there is no error in the query.

Comment: The second thing you should do is test, if you actually have any results. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Comment: @DevZer0 `die` might be a bit harsh. Raising an Exception might be the nicer thing to do. Think of the benefits in bigger projects: stack traces, error handling, graceful shutdown.

Comment: @scones `mysql_query` is procedural code, there is no need for raising an exception in this code here. If there is no data rest can't perform. Let's stick with the scope of the question, not get into a major architecture discussion IMHO

Comment: Does `$sensor1c .= (string) $data[0];` change anything?